# Filtering many-to-many relationships in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Another likely easy answer, but if I have a data structure called x.y that represents a many-to-many relationship, is there an easy way -- within the context of a django template -- to query x.y.all (or whatever) for a specific field, or do I need to set up a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that there's not really a better way to do it.
You could write a custom template tag if it was really arduous or something, but this
is probably what you're looking for.

```
{% for related in instance.some_related.all %}{{ related.field }}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
object.many_to_many_field.select_related().filter(field=something)
```

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't understand. Like the other answer, I have found no way to do this in a template since you can't pass any argument.